# KDE / ubuntu GNU/Linux, No option to suspend a Hard Driver?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, suspend

Im using the [KDE neon GNU/Linux](https://neon.kde.org/) (Upgraded to: ubuntu 18.04 - Kernel 4.20.5-1).
I have a **256GB M.2 SSD (sdb)** and a **1TB S-ATA HDD (sda)**.
I would like to suspend **HDD0 (sda, 1TB-HDD)** after 5 min. not in use, but i cant find the option to set it up.
How to suspend the HradDrive?

Comment: OK... i got it fixed: hdparm -B60 /dev/sda

Comment: It looks like you have found the answer. The right thing to do is to [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).